How can I add order of operation to a c++ calculator?
I'm making a c++ calculator that takes an unspecified amount of input that look like this "1 + 2 *3 -4 =" and it outputs the result, however I cannot figure out how to make it excute the multiplication and division first.
Here's the code:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float add(float num1, float num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}
float subtract(float num1, float num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
}
float multiply(float num1, float num2) {
    return num1 * num2;
}
float divide(float num1,float num2) {
    if (num2 == 0) {
        cout << "Cannot divide by 0";
    }
    return num1 / num2;
}

float calculate() {
    float num1, result;
    char op;
    bool loop = true;
    cin >> result;
    while (loop){
        cin >> op;
        if (op == '='){
            loop = false;
            break;
        }
        else {
            cin >> num1;
            switch(op) {
            case ('+'):
                result = add(result, num1);
                break;
            case ('-'):
                result = subtract(result, num1);
                break;
            case ('*'):
                result = multiply(result, num1);
                break;
            case ('/'):
                result = divide(result, num1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){
    cout << "Enter operation (first number, (+, -, *, /), second number): ";
    float final_number = calculate();
    cout << "The result is: " << final_number << endl;
    return 0;
}

I tried another method of making calculate() have recursion instead of a while loop and that didnt work and gave me a bunch of errors aswell.

You need to read all of the input, as text, into a buffer and parse it. Creating a simple infix calculator is among the first exercises in many compiler courses. There is plenty of literature, tutorials and examples all over the Internet.

You can use the Shunting Yard algorithm. There's many examples on SO of this problem.

To construct an expression tree, I'd use Boost Spirit X3, which is an eDSL you can use to specify a grammar and it will do the parsing.  If this is a class assignment, that might be overkill (and prohibited) because the professor wants you to write your own parser and construct your expression tree from scratch.  If this is for a real program, Spirit X3 is wonderful and can be used to specify tiny grammars to enormous grammars.

There are different ways/algorithms to do this, some are better and some are worse (if you build up a stack or a list or modify the string step by step ...).
So I also recommend to search for some literature or examples for how to do this exactly.
It is impossible to make suggestions how you should adapt your code to make it work, I can only give some general hints.
Basically you cannot just traverse the string from left to right if you want to support all math rules.

define priorities for your operations (or simply use a hardcoded processing  order)
parse the string into values and operators (how you store this depends on the algorithm)
search for the first highest priority operation and resolve/merge one operation and the two related values into one single value
repeat the process until you have only one value left

If you also want to deal with brackets then you could do this either recursively or increase the priority for every operator inside of the brackets.
For example + - could have priority 1 and * / have priority 2, then each opening/closing bracket may increase/decrease an offset by 10 which is added to every inner operation. Of course this highly depends on the desired algorithm.

First get the whole string and use a stack to store the numbers and operators.
Then use postfix notation to calculate the expression.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
